# dbt_utils union_relations column_override not working

Tags: dbt, dbt-utils

```
{{ dbt_utils.union_relations(
    relations=[
        ref('base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_apple_ads_spend'), 
        ref('base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_facebook_spend'),  
        ref('base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_tiktok_spend'), 
        ref('base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_google_spend')
        ],
    column_override={"digital_campaign_id":"TEXT"}
) }}
```

I am trying to use the `column_override` arg in the dbt_utils `union_relations` macro, but it doesn't seem to work when my code compiles.

```
(
            select
                cast('DBT_CCARREL.staging.base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_apple_ads_spend' as TEXT) as _dbt_source_relation,

                
                    cast("AD_DATE" as DATE) as "AD_DATE" ,
                    cast("ACQUISITION_PARTNER" as character varying(9)) as "ACQUISITION_PARTNER" ,
                    cast("DIGITAL_CAMPAIGN_ID" as NUMBER(38,0)) as "DIGITAL_CAMPAIGN_ID" ,
                    cast("DIGITAL_ADSET_ID" as NUMBER(38,0)) as "DIGITAL_ADSET_ID" ,
                    cast("DIGITAL_AD_ID" as NUMBER(38,0)) as "DIGITAL_AD_ID" ,
                    cast("IMPRESSIONS" as NUMBER(38,0)) as "IMPRESSIONS" ,
                    cast("CLICKS" as NUMBER(38,0)) as "CLICKS" ,
                    cast("SPEND" as NUMBER(18,4)) as "SPEND" ,
                    cast("AD_PERFORMANCE_UUID" as character varying(32)) as "AD_PERFORMANCE_UUID" 

            from DBT_CCARREL.staging.base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_apple_ads_spend

            
        )

        union all
```

Would love some help to understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/74a661ca00452da7d2b2811ff1e5a37f152c3ee2/macros/sql/union.sql#L109), I think `column_override` is case-sensitve (since in Python and Jinja, dictionary access is case-sensitive). So this should work:

```
{{ dbt_utils.union_relations(
    relations=[
        ref('base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_apple_ads_spend'), 
        ref('base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_facebook_spend'),  
        ref('base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_tiktok_spend'), 
        ref('base_consumer_digital_ad_performance_google_spend')
        ],
    column_override={"DIGITAL_CAMPAIGN_ID":"TEXT"}
) }}
```